# I want to porting zsh's function as fishshell

Tags: shell, command-line, fish

I have a question related to fishshell.

I wrote zsh's function as this:

```
function agvim() {
  vim $(ag "$@" | peco --query "$LBUFFER" | awk -F : '{print "-c " $2 " " $1}')
}
```

it works.

But I just ported this function doesn't work properly, this function is ported from zsh to fishshell.

```
function agvim
  ag $argv | peco --query "$LBUFFER" | awk -F : '{print "-c " $2 " " $1}' >> $HOME/.agvim_history
  vim (tail -n 1 $HOME/.agvim_history)
end
```

However it doesn't work properly. vim command will be opening with tail's output as filename.
because I think expand-command-substitution is a little different from the zsh.
This is tail's output example `-c 3 bin/ec` and I want to use this output as options.

Please tell me better solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why haven't you just done a straight up translation, without the cache file?

Answer (score 1):

> This is tail's output example -c 3 bin/ec and I want to use this output as options.

The issue you are running into here is that zsh, like bash, will split command substitutions on spaces, while fish only splits on newlines.

That means zsh will send "-c", "3" and "bin/ec" to vim, while fish will send "-c 3 bin/ec" as one argument.

There's a few ways to get around this - one, if you are running fish from git, is to use `tail | string split " "`. Another which should work with pretty much any fish version is to use sed (`tail | sed "s/ /\n/g"`).

Answer (score -1):

If you trust the input, this is a place to use `eval`

```
function agvim
  eval vim (ag $argv | peco --query "$LBUFFER" | awk -F: '{print "-c",$2,$1}')
end
```

Comment: Don't - it will break on anything that looks like an expansion to fish (which is anything starting with a $ and alphanumeric characters or in "()" or "{}". Though that script doesn't actually do any escaping at all, the issues will be exacerbated by running it through eval.